# Push notifications not working on live production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My code is working properly on local environment but notifications arn't working on production. I'm using **angular 8**. Firebase 7.6.0 is being used.
When I am sending push notification from firebase console, it is working fine but when some request is hitting from live server admin panel then notifications are not sent. **Node.js** is used for Backend.

```
 constructor(private messagingService: MessagingService){
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      console.log('--------in service qorker condition')
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("./firebase-messaging-sw.js").then(
            function(registration) {
            console.log(
                "ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ",
                registration.scope
              );
            },
            function(err) {
              // registration failed :(
              console.log("ServiceWorker registration failed: ", err);
            }
          );
        });
      }

  }

 ngOnInit() {
    // const userId = 'user001';
    // this.messagingService.requestPermission(userId);
    this.messagingService.receiveMessage();
  }
```

Above  is `app.component.ts` constructor call

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
  token: any = "";
currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
constructor(private angularFireDB: AngularFireDatabase,
  private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
  this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
   (_messaging) => {
    _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
    _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
    }
  )
}

updateToken(userId, token) {
  // we can change this function to request our backend service
  this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
    () => {
      const data = {};
      data[userId] = token
      this.angularFireDB.object('fcmTokens/').update(data)
    })
}
requestPermission(userId) {
this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
 (token) => {
  console.log(token);
  this.token = token;
  this.updateToken(userId, token);
 },
 (err) => {
  console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
 }
 );
}


receiveMessage() {

  this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload: any) => {
    if (payload) {
      console.log(payload, '----lasjkdfl');
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(service_worker) {
        service_worker.showNotification(payload.notification.title, {
          body: payload.notification.body
        });
      });
      console.log("new message received. ", payload);
      this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    }
    else{
console.log("no payload recieved");
    }
  });
}
}
```

Above is messaging service

```
 this.messagingService.requestPermission(userId);
 this.messagingService.receiveMessage();
 this.message = this.messagingService.currentMessage;
```

Above code is called in `login.component.ts`

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

Above is firebase-messaging-sw.js configuration

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same error, did u solve this problem, please help.Thanks